# Converting riemann sum to definite integral

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Another Riemann sum I'm struggling to convert to a definite integral... $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\sum_{i=1}^n$ $\frac{6n}{9n^2+4i^2}$. Any ideas as to what my $x_i$ should be in this case?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683256/when-converting-a-riemann-sum-to-an-integral-how-does-one-decide-the-bounds-of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_i=\dfrac{i}{n}$ then $x_1=\dfrac{1}{n}\to0$, $x_n=\dfrac{n}{n}\to1$and $\Delta x=\dfrac1n$ so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{6}{9+4(\dfrac{i}{n})^2}\frac1n=\int_0^1\dfrac{6}{9+4x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{6n}{9n^2 + 4i^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{6}{9 + 4(i/n)^2} \; \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \; \int_{0}^{1} \frac{6}{9 + 4t^2} \; dt. $$

---

This follows from the following result.

If $f$ is a *continuous* real-valued function defined on $[a,b]$ ($a < b$) then:

$$ \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\Big( a + k\frac{b-a}{n} \Big) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \; dt. $$

Take $a = 0$, $b = 1$ and $\displaystyle f \, : \, t \, \mapsto \, 6/(9 + 4t^2)$.

Comment: How is this a hint.  It's literally the answer.

Comment: @DionelJaime : Not completely. It remains to compute the integral to have a _final_ result... But I agree, it's a big hint.

Comment: Lmao, I dont mind, I'm new to Riemann sums so i'll study ur steps closely. I appreciate your help =)

Comment: @novo : I added the result on Riemann sums hopping that it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how do we go from $\frac{6n}{9n^2+4i^2}$ to $\frac{6}{9+4(i/n)^2}$. Does $i = \frac{i}{n}$ here? And how does the n and n^2 from 6 and 9 dissapear?

Comment: @novo : Inside the sum, factor $1/n^2$. The idea is to put something like $(b-a)/n$ in front of the sum. You factor $1/n^2$ inside the sum but a $n$ cancels out with the one from $6n$ in the numerator. That leaves you with $1/n$ in front of the sum.

Comment: Damn, the most simple things.... Thank you again sir!