# When converting a Riemann sum to an integral, how does one decide the bounds of the converted Riemann sum?

Tags: calculus, integration

Context problem: $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{r=2n} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+n^2}}$$

So the thing messing me up is the '2n' in the upper of sum, I've already figured out that the function which this rienman integral is ( $ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$)

Comment: There are worthier answers than mine which should very satisfactorily answer your question. I request you to un-accept my answer and choose an answer that you consider the best.

Comment: you have lost the answer acceptance but have gained my respect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And now a synthesis of the other two answers that involves less (apparent) guessing than one and slightly more precision than the other.

Suppose what you are given is a Riemann sum similar to the ones you performed by hand when introduced to the concept of Riemann sums ([left Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_sum), right Riemann sum, midpoint ...)  Then you expect that you are looking at an expression of the form
$$  \lim_{\text{the partition shrinks}} \Delta x \sum \text{sample heights}  $$
So provisionally, we take $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$.  (Provisionally, because our subsequent algebraic manipulations may result in modifying this term.)

The sum you are given uses $r$ as the index, so $r$ is which member of the partition we are sampling.  We have $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$, so we expect the sample points to be (not necessarily exactly) $1/n$ apart, so sampled at $r$ steps of size $1/n$, which is $r/n$.  So we want to algebraically manipulate the summand so that all occurrences of $r$ are of the form $r/n$.  \begin{align*}
\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + n^2}}  
&=  \frac{n \cdot r/n}{\sqrt{n^2 \cdot (r/n)^2 + n^2}}  \\
&=  \frac{n \cdot r/n}{\sqrt{n^2 \cdot \left( (r/n)^2 + n^2/n^2 \right)}}  \\
&=  \frac{n \cdot r/n}{n \sqrt{(r/n)^2 + 1 }}  \\
&=  \frac{r/n}{\sqrt{(r/n)^2 + 1 }}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
(Technicality: in the denominator, we wrote $\sqrt{n^2} = n$.  This isn't quite right.  $\sqrt{n^2} = |n|$.  However, we have $0 < n$, so $|n| = n$ here.)

Having succeeded, we know that the sample points of the function $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ occur at $x = r/n$.  (There is a comment about horizontal translation and scaling below that may be of use to some readers at this point.)  And these *are* separated by $1/n$, so $\Delta x = 1/n$ is promoted from provisionally correct to correct.  If this were not the case, our job would be to find $p$ so that $\Delta x = 1/n^p$ appears in front of the sum and $r$ appears in the combination $r/n^p$ throughout.  (This depends on the fact that the summand/integrand is an [algebraic fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_fraction), so such a $p$ can be found.  If the integrand is more complicated, $\Delta x$ and the combination in which $r$ appears may be more complicated.)

But now we know the endpoints.  Since $x$ is $r/n$, and $r$ ranges from $1$ to $2n$, we need to take the limits of the left-most $x$, $1/n$ and the right-most $x$, $2n/n$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n &= 0  \text{ and }  \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2n/n &= 2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
From which, we know that *an* integral equivalent to our sum is
$$  \int_0^2 \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \,\mathrm{d}x \text{.}  $$

Why do I say "*an*"?  Because there are many integrals equivalent to our sum.  Here's another.
$$  \int_7^9 \frac{u-7}{\sqrt{u^2 - 14u + 50}} \,\mathrm{d}u \text{,}  $$
which is obtained by translating the previous integral to the right by $7$ units.  That is, by the substitution $u = x+7$.  We can make this integral be the one we land on by making $\frac{r}{n} + 7$ be the combination in which $r$ appears.
\begin{align*}
\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + n^2}}  
&=  \frac{n \cdot ((r/n+7) - 7)}{\sqrt{n^2 \cdot ((r/n+7) - 7)^2 + n^2}}  \\
&=  \frac{n \cdot ((r/n+7) - 7)}{\sqrt{n^2 \cdot \left( ((r/n+7) - 7)^2 + n^2/n^2 \right)}}  \\
&=  \frac{n \cdot ((r/n+7) - 7)}{n \cdot \sqrt{ ((r/n+7) - 7)^2 + 1}}  \\
&= \frac{(r/n+7) - 7}{\sqrt{(r/n+7)^2 - 14(r/n+7) + 50}}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
With $x = \frac{r}{n} + 7$, the integrand and limits of integration are
$$  \frac{x-7}{\sqrt{x^2 - 14x + 50}}  \text{,}  $$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} + 7 &= 7 \text{, and }  \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n}{n} + 7 &= 9 \text{.}
\end{align*}

We can even scale $x$ to $kr/n$ for $k \neq 0$.  Similarly to the translation, we algebraically force the combination of $r$ to match.  Unlike translation, our $\Delta x$ changes to $k/n$.  (This should be unsurprising.  When you make the substitution $u = kx$, you scale the variable in the integrand *and* scale the differential element.)

I mention translation and scaling to *remove* a common worry by students.  There are *many* integrals corresponding to the sum you are given differing by scaling and translation.  You only have to find one such integral.  The integral that is easiest to find has $r$ appearing in a simple combination (no translation) and $\Delta x$ appearing without a constant multiplier (no scaling).  You can *always* find the "simpler" integral (lacking translation or scaling) using the procedure we described first.

Comment: this answer and the other one have convinced me of un-worthiness of the accept. I shall request the OP to choose a better answer than mine...

Answer (score 14):

You can start with well known result that *if a function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ then $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a} {n} \sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(a+r\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\tag{1}$$*

The problem with your limit in question is that the summation index varies from $r=1$ to $r=2n$ instead of $r=1$ to $r=n$. This is the part which is easy to handle. Just replace $n$ by $2n$ in the formula $(1) $ and get the expression under limit in $(1)$ as $$\frac{b-a} {2n}\sum_{r=1}^{2n}f\left(a+r\cdot\frac{b-a}{2n}\right)\tag{2}$$ and try to compare the expression under limit in question with the above expression. You can always replace $n$ by any function of $n$ eg $n^2$ which is strictly increasing with $n$ and takes positive integer values and tends to $\infty $ and thereby deal with even weirder sums.

An easy guess is $(b-a) /2n=1/n$ so that $b-a=2$. Next rewrite the expression under summation as $$\frac{r/n}{\sqrt{1+(r/n)^2}}=\frac{r(b-a)/(2n)}{\sqrt{1+(r(b-a)/(2n))^2}}\tag{3}$$ and the last expression appears to be some function of $r(b-a) /(2n)$ (instead of a function of $a+r(b-a) /(2n)$). This gives another guess as $a=0$ and then $b=2$. The function $f$ in $(3)$ is easily guessed by replacing the $r(b-a)/(2n)$ with a single letter $x$ and we have $$f(x) =\frac{x} {\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ and finally your limit is $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The upper limit of the integral can be simply written by answering the question:
"How many times of $n$ is the upper limit of the sum?"

The other substitutions would be $\dfrac1n 
 \to \mathrm{d}x$ and $\dfrac rn \to x$

The answer to the question mentioned works to give you the right solution because of the substitution $\dfrac rn\to x$ . When $r=1, x=\dfrac 1n \text{ which} \to 0 \because n\to \infty. $ If the upper limit was $kn+c$ for some random sum, then for the upper lmit of the said integral to be calculated would still be $k$ , again because of the substitution for $x$. When $r=kn+c , x=\dfrac{kn+c}{n}=k+\dfrac cn=k \ \ (\because n\to \infty)$

This should help you find the upper/lower bounds for any sum that you would like to convert to an integral

Comment: Better avoid such things like $1/n\to dx$ and $r/n\to x$. This is not how a Riemann sum works. Instead add a proper definition of Riemann sum (even a simplified one with uniform partitions would be fine here) and then get the desired integral.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I'm really sorry I have not much knowledge about what you mentioned. However I use these just for quicker calculation

Comment: No worry! I have given an answer which you may find useful in this regard.